# how to prevent default collapse behavior on div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to give a list of items I'm iterating over the ability to collapse and uncollapse again when pressing a hide button.

Pretty easy to do using bootsraps `collapse` class and setting up the appropriate anchor link / id references.

However, the first time I click the button it will collapse and then unhide the element again. Because I haven't set the initial collapse class (because I want it to show by default). After this everything runs smoothly it's just the first click that doesn't work properly.

How would I go about preventing this default behavior?

I know I could switch out the bootstrap class for a button / jQuery using the collapse class just seems to be a better way to integrate the feature.

Edit: updated bootply for non-working vs working first click

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/LAxIsZWWRR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you want to be initially visible still needs the `collapse` class. To show it by default just add the `in` class as well. Updated your [bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/waPLYw2TqF) with an example